# How to read specific data from a csv file and delete it?

Tags: java, excel, file, csv, delete-row

I am coding a program for a personal trainer to manage clients, I want to be able to remove clients off of the database (an Excel spreadsheet) and I also want to be able to read their plans from another database ( another Excel Spreadsheet). I am unsure how to delete people from a spreadsheet using Java. Secondly, I am unsure how to read a section from a spreadsheet, for example, if the client's plan starts on row 11 and ends on row 21, how do I read this data from the sheet? The thing is in the program we won't actually know what rows the client's plan are stored on, so I know that I will have to use if statements to compare the data to what I am looking for. Once I have read the data from the file, I also want to delete it. Below is an example of what the plan looks like:

[image]

Below is the current code I have:

```
if(workoutPlan.isVisible()==true){
            BufferedReader br = null;
            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Client Workout Plans.csv"));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            String line = "";
            String cvsSplitBy = ",";
            String fullName = null;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Clients.csv"));
                boolean complete = false;
                while(complete!=true){
                    try {
                        line = br.readLine();
                        String[] data = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
                        String Name = existingClient.getFirst()+" "+existingClient.getLast();
                        int fullNameLength = Name.length(); 
                        if((data.length>0)&&((data[0].substring(0, fullNameLength)).equals(Name))){

                        }
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To read and write csv files, you can use Commons CSV: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/